# How to not let parent css impact css of a child component?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have created a react app, which is basically a widget that can be included on any HTML page, however when mounted on different pages, its CSS is getting affected. I want the CSS of this react app to be solid and not affected by its parent page's CSS. I have index.scss which has font-family etc. defined for body and code. Everywhere else I have used styled components to create custom components with their respective CSS properties.
I want to know if it's possible that my styled component's CSS is getting overridden. Can CSS modules resolve my problem?

Comment: did you find a reasonable solution for this

Comment: @nikit have all css put into properly named classes or namespaces which wont match with any parent style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use pseudo-namespacing to differentiate contexts. I would not use `!important` unless as a last resort because a) you don't need it at all, and b) it makes overwriting the overwrite that much harder.

```html
<div id="aboutUs" class="foo">
  <span class="bar"></span>
</div>
```

```css
.foo {
  /* Default styles */
}
#aboutUs.foo {
  /* Override defaults */
}
#aboutUs .bar {
  /* Override defaults */
}
```

I suggest checking out how cascading works: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Cascade

Answer (score 0):

#### 1: Normalize your styling

For example if you have a `<div>` that is having it's `position` modified by styling on a page, you can manually set that `position` to what it should be on said `<div>` so that it doesn't rely on inheritance.

For example:

```
/* Global styling that will affect '.my-app div' */
div {
  display: flex;
}

/* Override global styling by manually setting display, instead of relying on it's supposed default value */
.my-app div {
  display: block;
}
```

#### 2. Use !important

Add the `!important` tag to your styles so that they are prioritized.

```
.my-class {
  display: flex !important;
}
```

Comment: There's rarely a good reason to use `!important`. It will just make it harder when you need to style another component that's a child of `my-class` or an element with that class is used in a different context, as there's no `!!important` or `!!!important`.